# To get the values in responseText in an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, responsetext

I'm trying to get values from the table based on the eqid using the sendxmlRequest() method:

```
 <select name="eqNAME" onchange="sendxmlRequest('GET','getEquipDetails.jsp',this.value)
 <options> ..... <options>
 </select>
```

This I have added in ajax.js file

```
//Make the XMLHttpRequest Object
var http = createRequestObject();
function sendxmlRequest(method, url,eqid){
    url = url + "?eqid="+eqid;
     if(method == 'get' || method == 'GET'){
    http.open(method,url,true);
    http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
    http.send(null);
    }
}    

function createRequestObject(){
    var req; try {
    // Firefox, Opera, Safari
    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
    // Internet Explorer
    try {
    //For IE 6
    req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
    try {
    //For IE 5
    req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
         catch (e) {
     alert('Your browser is not IE 5 or higher, or Firefox or Safari or Opera');
     }
   }
}
return req;
```

}

The following is used to handle the response (in ajax.js):

```
function handleResponse(){
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
    var response = http.responseText;
}
}
```

Here is my 'getEquipDetails.jsp' file:

```
<% 
String planLoc= theResult1.getString(2) == null ? "":theResult1.getString(3);
String changLoc= theResult1.getString(3) == null ? "":theResult1.getString(4)
%> 
<%
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, private, no-store, max-stale=0"); //  HTTP 1.1
%>
```

My query is, how do we get the values planLoc and changLoc from the getEquipDetails.jsp and set it in responseText, so that it can be updated in the drop-down in my page?

Or is there any other way to go about it?

Note: I haven't given the table retrieval code, since that is already taken care of. I just want the planLoc and changLoc updated in my JSP page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `getEquipDetails.jsp`

Write values `response.getWriter()`  object.

```
<%
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, private, no-store, max-stale=0"); //  HTTP 1.1
PrintWriter res = response.getWriter();
res.println(planLoc);
res.println(changLoc);
res.close();
%>
```

Then In

```
function handleResponse(){
  if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
    document.getElementById("dataTable").innerHTML = http.responseText;  
    // dataTable will be id of any HTML tag where you want to display the updated value.
  }
}
```

For Example:

```
<div id="dataTable"></div>
```

So, Response from AJAX will be set here.